# XML filter criteria

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to change the following criteria. Currently it look through entire xml and print unique classes. But I want the criteria so that instead of looking for same class in entire xml, it checks if previous class is same as current. If previous class is different , then treat as a new class.
Currently the xslt is creating table based on unique class in the xml ( see the xml).
e.g if xml has class
A
B
B
A

it create two tables only. one table for class A with two records and one table with class B of 2 records. But I was three tables. first table of class A with one record ( because next class is different), next table of class B with 2 records ( because B has two records in sequence) and then next table of class A with one record ( because previous record belongs to class B). So in brief the sequence of table creation should happen like class A, Class B, Class A.
 Here is the xslt.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:DBE="http://www.sdrc.com/metaphase/cf11bd">



    <!-- Input Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="reportDate"/>
    <xsl:param name="reportTitle"/>
    <xsl:param name="reportLocale"/>
    <xsl:param name="thinClientURLPrefix"/>


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="baseUrl" select="'FIXME'"/>

    <!-- Specify TextBundle file to read text entries from -->
    <xsl:variable name="textBundleURI" select="'tc50_default_TextBundle.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="defaultTextBundleRoot" select="document($textBundleURI)"/>

    <!--*************************************************************************-->
    <!--*** Template for the Root of the XML Report document ********************-->
    <!--*************************************************************************-->

    <xsl:template match="/">

       <HTML>
          <HEAD>
             <TITLE> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$reportTitle"/>
             </TITLE>
          </HEAD>

          <BODY>
             <CENTER>
                <FONT>
                </FONT>
             </CENTER>
             <BR/>
                <TABLE border="0" align="center" width="90%">
                <TR>
                   <TD width="95%">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$reportTitle"/>
                      </TD>

                    <TD>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$reportDate"/>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
             </TABLE>

             <BR/>
             <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object) &gt; 0">

             <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_unique_classes"
         select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object
             [not(./@Class=preceding-sibling::DBE:Object/@Class)]"/>

                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <CENTER><B>
                   <xsl:call-template name="GetTextFromBundle">
                      <xsl:with-param name="textID" select="'NO_ITEMS_FOUND'"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                   </B></CENTER>
                </xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
             <TABLE border="0">
             <form name="myForm">
    <tr>
        <th><input name="Print" type="button" value="Print" onclick="javascript:window.print()" style="font: bold 12px Arial;background-color:transparent"/>
        </th>
        <th><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs', true)" style="font: bold 12px Arial;background-color:transparent"/>
        </th>
    </tr> 
    </form>
    </TABLE>
          </BODY>
       </HTML>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="DBE:Object" mode="print_unique_classes">

      <xsl:variable name="className" select="./DBE:Attribute[@name='Class']/DBE:Translation"/>
      <TABLE>
        <TR>
        <TD bgcolor="#C3E1FF" > 
           <xsl:value-of select="$className"/>
        </TD>
        <xsl:variable name="classNameAct" select="./DBE:Attribute[@name='Class']/DBE:String"/>
        <xsl:if test="$classNameAct = 'x0EcnPrd' or $classNameAct = 'x0EcnNSR' or $classNameAct = 'x0EcnSR' or $classNameAct = 'x0EcnSOP'">
        <TD>&#160;&#160;:&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</TD>
        <TD bgcolor="#FF7979" >
          <xsl:variable name="changeid" select="./DBE:Attribute[@name='x0ChangeId']/DBE:String"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$changeid"/>
        </TD>
        </xsl:if>

        </TR>
      </TABLE>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_item_class"  select="." />      
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template mode="print_item_class" match="DBE:Object">

       <xsl:variable name="className" select="./@Class"/>

       <TABLE border="1" align="center" width="90%">

          <TR>
             <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_table_column_names"  select="./DBE:Attribute" />      
          </TR>

          <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_similar_item_classes"
                  select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object[@Class=$className]"/>

      </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template mode="print_table_column_names" match="DBE:Object/DBE:Attribute">
       <xsl:variable name="columnName" select="./@name"/>

       <xsl:if test="not(contains($columnName, 'OBID'))" >
        <xsl:if test="not(contains($columnName, 'Class'))" >
           <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'Left' or $columnName = 'LeftMember')">
                <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'Right' or  $columnName = 'RightMember')">
                  <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'NavTplName' or  $columnName = 'CustTplMsgName' or $columnName = 'CustTplMsgClassName' or  $columnName = 'CustTplDialogName')">
                    <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'XrfItemHandle')">
                   <TH  bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                         <xsl:variable name="columnDisplayName" select="./@displayAs"/>
                     <xsl:value-of select="$columnDisplayName"/>
                   </TH>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
             </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template mode="print_similar_item_classes" match="DBE:Object">
        <TR>  
           <xsl:variable name="xrfItemHandle" select="./DBE:Attribute[@name='XrfItemHandle']/DBE:String"/>

           <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_column_vlaues" select="./DBE:Attribute">
              <xsl:with-param name="xrfItemHandle" select="$xrfItemHandle"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>

        </TR> 
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template mode="print_column_vlaues" match="DBE:Object/DBE:Attribute">
       <xsl:param name="xrfItemHandle"/>
       <xsl:param name="isRelation"/>

       <xsl:variable name="columnName" select="./@name"/>
       <xsl:if test="not(contains($columnName, 'OBID'))" >
       <xsl:if test="not(contains($columnName, 'Class'))" >
           <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'Left' or $columnName = 'LeftMember')">
                <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'Right' or  $columnName = 'RightMember')">
                              <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'NavTplName' or  $columnName = 'CustTplMsgName' or $columnName = 'CustTplMsgClassName' or  $columnName = 'CustTplDialogName')">
                    <xsl:if test="not($columnName = 'XrfItemHandle')">
                      <xsl:apply-templates mode="print_filtered_column_vlaues" select=".">
                      <xsl:with-param name="xrfItemHandle" select="$xrfItemHandle"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="isRelation" select="$isRelation"/>
                       </xsl:apply-templates>      
                    </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:if>
                 </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="print_filtered_column_vlaues" match="DBE:Object/DBE:Attribute">
       <xsl:param name="xrfItemHandle"/>
       <xsl:param name="isRelation"/>

       <xsl:variable name="columnType" select="./@type"/>
       <xsl:variable name="columnName" select="./@name"/>

       <xsl:choose>

            <xsl:when test="$columnName != 'DisplayedName' and $columnName != 'Class' and $columnType = 'String' ">
                <xsl:variable name="transValue" select="./DBE:Translation"/>
                <xsl:if test="string($transValue)" >
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="$transValue"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(string($transValue))" >
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:String"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'String' ">

                <xsl:variable name="transValue" select="./DBE:Translation"/>
                <xsl:if test="string($transValue)" > 
               <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
               <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="$transValue"/>
               </xsl:call-template>     
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(string($transValue))" > 
               <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
               <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:String"/>
               </xsl:call-template>     
                </xsl:if>

        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Timestamp' ">

                <xsl:variable name="transValue" select="./DBE:Translation"/>
                <xsl:if test="string($transValue)" > 
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="$transValue"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(string($transValue))" >
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:Timestamp"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>

        </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Boolean' ">

                <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:Boolean"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'List' ">

                <xsl:call-template name="print_list_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="listValues" select="./DBE:List"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Table' ">
                <xsl:call-template name="print_table_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="tableValues" select="./DBE:Table"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'StringStar' ">

                <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:StringStar"/>
                </xsl:call-template>

            </xsl:when>

           <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Integer' ">
                <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:Integer"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:when>

           <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Float' ">
                <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:Float"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
           </xsl:when>

           <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Date' ">
                <xsl:variable name="transValue" select="./DBE:Translation"/>
                <xsl:if test="string($transValue)" >
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="$transValue"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(string($transValue))" >
                   <xsl:call-template name="print_column_value">
                       <xsl:with-param name="colValue" select="./DBE:Date"/>
                   </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>



           <xsl:when test="$columnType = 'Object' ">
            <TD>
               ---
            </TD>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <TD>
               ---
            </TD>
        </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="print_displayed_name_column" >
       <xsl:param name="colValue"/>
       <xsl:param name="itemHandle"/>
       <xsl:param name="isRelation"/>

           <!-- move to global
           <xsl:variable name="baseUrl" select="'http://mspm117:8080/change-l'"/>
           -->

           <xsl:if test="string($isRelation)">
               <TD>
                   <xsl:value-of select="$colValue"/>
           </TD>
           </xsl:if>

           <xsl:if test="not(string($isRelation))">
             <xsl:if test="string($itemHandle)">
              <xsl:variable name="relativeUrl"
                 select="'/controller/home?sdrcStartupPage=eds_open_generic_open_link&amp;'"/>
              <xsl:variable name="urlParams" select="'item_handle_param='"/>
              <xsl:variable name="urlParamsValue" select="$itemHandle"/>


              <xsl:if test="string($thinClientURLPrefix)">
                 <xsl:variable name="completeURL" select="concat($thinClientURLPrefix,$relativeUrl,
                                  $urlParams,$urlParamsValue)"/>
                 <TD>
                     <a href="{$completeURL}" target="_blank">
                         <xsl:value-of select="$colValue"/>
                     </a>
                 </TD>
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="not(string($thinClientURLPrefix))">
                 <xsl:variable name="completeURL" select="concat($baseUrl,$relativeUrl,
                                  $urlParams,$urlParamsValue)"/>
                 <TD>
                     <a href="{$completeURL}" target="_blank">
                         <xsl:value-of select="$colValue"/>
                     </a>
                 </TD>
               </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="print_column_value" >
       <xsl:param name="colValue"/>

        <xsl:if test="string($colValue)"> 
           <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="$colValue"/> 
           </TD>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not(string($colValue))">
           <TD>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text> 
           </TD>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="print_list_column_value" >
       <xsl:param name="listValues"/>

        <TD>
           <TABLE>
             <xsl:for-each select="$listValues/DBE:ListMember">

                 <xsl:variable name="listmemeber" select="."/>

                 <!-- FIXME: Dont know how to handle spaces inside string
                   normalize-space(.)
                 <xsl:value-of select="concat($listmemeber,',')" />       
                 -->

                <TR>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$listmemeber" />       
                </TR>

             </xsl:for-each>       
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="print_table_column_value" >
       <xsl:param name="tableValues"/>

        <TD>
           <TABLE>

             <xsl:for-each select="$tableValues/DBE:TableHeader">
                 <TR>
                    <xsl:variable name="tablecolumn" select="."/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$tablecolumn/DBE:TableColumn">
                       <TD>
                           <xsl:value-of select="." />
                       </TD>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </TR>
              </xsl:for-each>

             <xsl:for-each select="$tableValues/DBE:TableRow">
                <TR>
                   <xsl:variable name="tablerow" select="."/>
                   <xsl:for-each select="$tablerow/DBE:TableData">
                       <xsl:variable name="tabledata" select="."/>
                       <TD>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$tabledata" />
                       </TD>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                 </TR>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </TABLE>
        </TD>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetTextFromBundle">
       <xsl:param name="textBundle" select="$defaultTextBundleRoot"/>
       <xsl:param name="textID"/>

       <xsl:variable name="text"
             select="$defaultTextBundleRoot/IDMap/TextID[@name=$textID]/@text"/>

       <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length($text) &gt; '0'">
             <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:value-of select="$textID" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>


    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the xml

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ECNSIGNOFF_default_html_classic_StylesheetF.xsl"?>
<!--
The DOCTYPE command is commented out for Internet Explorer compatibility.



<!DOCTYPE DBE:ObjectSetRoot SYSTEM "/ees/pdm/apps/epi/sb/tc8.1/product/xml/bd2.dtd">

--><DBE:ObjectSetRoot xmlns:DBE="http://www.sdrc.com/metaphase/cf11bd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sdrc.com/metaphase/cf11bd /ees/pdm/apps/epi/sb/tc8.1/product/xml/bd2.xsd">

<DBE:Object Class="x1ENSREB">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x1ENSREB</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>ECN-NSR Implements Document</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
    <DBE:Attribute name="x0ChgDesc" type="String" displayAs="Description of Change (what?)" length="2000">
        <DBE:String>ECN</DBE:String>
    </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="x0EcnChgType" type="String" displayAs="Type of Change" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x0NSR</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>Non-saleable</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
</DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="x4SvcPln">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x4SvcPln</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>Service Plan</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="Creator" type="String" displayAs="Last Modified By" length="30">
      <DBE:String>super user</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="DocumentName" type="String" displayAs="Document Number" length="80">
      <DBE:String>SP000001</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>

</DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="DocSig">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>DocSig</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>DocSig</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="CurrentUser" type="String" displayAs="Current Assigned User" length="80">
      <DBE:String>super user</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="ExtStamp" type="String" displayAs="Signature Stamp" length="30">
      <DBE:String/>
   </DBE:Attribute>

</DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="DocSig">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>DocSig</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>DocSig</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="CurrentUser" type="String" displayAs="Current Assigned User" length="80">
      <DBE:String>super user</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="ExtStamp" type="String" displayAs="Signature Stamp" length="30">
      <DBE:String/>
   </DBE:Attribute>
  </DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="DocSig">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>DocSig</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>DocSig</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="CurrentUser" type="String" displayAs="Current Assigned User" length="80">
      <DBE:String>Author</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="ExtStamp" type="String" displayAs="Signature Stamp" length="30">
      <DBE:String/>
   </DBE:Attribute>

</DBE:Object>


<DBE:Object Class="x1ENSREB">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x1ENSREB</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>ECN-NSR Implements Document</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>

   <DBE:Attribute name="x0ChgDesc" type="String" displayAs="Description of Change (what?)" length="2000">
      <DBE:String>test ECN</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="x0EcnChgType" type="String" displayAs="Type of Change" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x0NSR</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>Non-saleable</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
</DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="x4SvcPln">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>x4SvcPln</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>Service Plan</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="Creator" type="String" displayAs="Last Modified By" length="30">
      <DBE:String>super user</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="DocumentName" type="String" displayAs="Document Number" length="80">
      <DBE:String>SP000002</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>

</DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="DocSig">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>DocSig</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>DocSig</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="CurrentUser" type="String" displayAs="Current Assigned User" length="80">
      <DBE:String>super user</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="ExtStamp" type="String" displayAs="Signature Stamp" length="30">
      <DBE:String/>
   </DBE:Attribute>
  </DBE:Object>

<DBE:Object Class="DocSig">
   <DBE:Attribute name="Class" type="String" displayAs="Class" length="20">
      <DBE:String>DocSig</DBE:String>
      <DBE:Translation>DocSig</DBE:Translation>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="CurrentUser" type="String" displayAs="Current Assigned User" length="80">
      <DBE:String>consumer</DBE:String>
   </DBE:Attribute>
   <DBE:Attribute name="ExtStamp" type="String" displayAs="Signature Stamp" length="30">
      <DBE:String/>
   </DBE:Attribute>
       </DBE:Object>


</DBE:ObjectSetRoot>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter criteria in xslt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690974/filter-criteria-in-xslt)

Comment: Is your XML correct? The XML contains 6 **DBE:Object** elements, for 3 distinct classes (A B C A B C) but your question suggests you only have 4 objects with just 2 distinct classes (A B B A).

Comment: XMl is correct. I modified it further to add two more DBE objects. If you see the xml , it has now 8 DBE:OBjects with classes as A,B,C,C,A,B,C,C. It is creating the tables with 2 records of A, 2 records of B and 4 records of C. But I want it to create first table of A with 1 record ( because next class is different), B with 1 record, C with 2 records, then A with 1 record, B with 1 record and C with 2 records.

Comment: I think you have A,B,C,C,C,A,B,C,C here.... But still, I have expanded my answer to give more information and hopefully solve your issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is replace this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="print_unique_classes"
     select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object
         [not(./@Class=preceding-sibling::DBE:Object/@Class)]"/>
```

With this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="print_unique_classes"
     select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object
         [not(./@Class=preceding-sibling::DBE:Object[1]/@Class)]"/>
```

It is the **DBE:Object[1]** that will restrict the check to only looking at the first preceding sibling here.

Also, you will also need to get all the items in the 'table'. In the template for "print_item_class" you may need to replace this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="print_similar_item_classes"
     select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object[@Class=$className]"/>
```

With this line

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="following-sibling::DBE:Object[1][@Class=current()/@Class]" 
     mode="print_item_class" />
```

Your current line will get all items with the same class, whereas the amended line will only get the following-siblings with the same name up until the class changes.

Sometimes though, it is best to simplify a problem. Reduce it to the very basic, and build upon it. Try this XLST for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:DBE="http://www.sdrc.com/metaphase/cf11bd" exclude-result-prefixes="DBE">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/DBE:ObjectSetRoot/DBE:Object[not(./@Class=preceding-sibling::DBE:Object[1]/@Class)]" mode="print_unique_classes"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DBE:Object" mode="print_unique_classes">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="print_item_class" />
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="DBE:Object" mode="print_item_class">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="@Class" /></li>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::DBE:Object[1][@Class=current()/@Class]" mode="print_item_class" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output. I have output lists, rather than tables, just to demonstrate the principle.

```
<ul>
   <li>x1ENSREB</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>x4SvcPln</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>DocSig</li>
   <li>DocSig</li>
   <li>DocSig</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>x1ENSREB</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>x4SvcPln</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>DocSig</li>
   <li>DocSig</li>
</ul>
```

Now, if you could use XSLT2.0, then **xsl:for-each-group** could be your new best friend. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:DBE="http://www.sdrc.com/metaphase/cf11bd" exclude-result-prefixes="DBE">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="DBE:Object" group-adjacent="@Class">
         <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
               <li>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Class"/>
               </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </ul>
         <xsl:text/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should also give the same results.

Hopefully, you will be able to build on this to output the tables you want.

Comment: I tried that, but still same result. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Hmmm... It might help if you posted your full XSLT, and your expected XML. Thanks!

Comment: I am unable to post complete xslt due to words limitation. Is there any other way? thanks

Comment: You should edit the original question with the full XSLT, rather than try to add it as a comment. It is much easier to read that way.

Comment: I just added the xml and xslt. Thanks

Comment: @ComputerEngineer, Please, edit again and also add the exact wanted result.